# 7th gen iPod radio with a bluetooth headset in motorcycle helmet

Tags: bluetooth, ipod

I have just bought a 7th generation iPod and I have a bluetooth headset in a motorcycle helmet. Is there any way to listen to the radio through bluetooth given that the headphones are the antenna?

Comment: If you can link to the Apple definition of 7th gen or provide a specific detail someone might have a better answer than "no". Although, no might be the correct answer even with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about an iPod nano.

> iPod nano uses the headphone cord as an antenna, so you must connect headphones to iPod nano to receive a radio signal. For better reception, make sure the cord isn’t tangled or coiled.
>   **FM radio will not play through a Bluetooth accessory.**

Source: [Apple support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202586)